# Image not showing up AND UIImagePickerController not showing up

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I have this code inside of a collectionViewCell:

```
lazy var logoImageView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: "yeee")
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 25
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSelectProfileImageView)))
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    return imageView
}()

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])  {
    picker.delegate = self as? UIImagePickerControllerDelegate & UINavigationControllerDelegate
    var selectedImageFromPicker: UIImage?

    if let editedImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"] as? UIImage {

        selectedImageFromPicker = editedImage

    } else if let originalImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as? UIImage {
        selectedImageFromPicker = originalImage
    }

    if let selectedImage = selectedImageFromPicker {
        logoImageView.image = selectedImage
    }
}
```

When I build the application, neither the image named "yeee" shows up, nor the image when I select it using the imagePickerController. I know this question has already been asked, but none of the answers have solved my issue.

When I change:
    `imageView.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: "yeee")`
to `imageView.image = UIImage(named: "yeee")`, the image named "yeee" appears, but the image chosen from the UIImagePickerController does not show up. What should I do?

UPDATE:

```
func handleSelectProfileImageView() {
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = self as? UIImagePickerControllerDelegate & UINavigationControllerDelegate
    picker.allowsEditing = true
    present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: where you are presenting UIImagePicker

Comment: And do 'picker.delegate = self as? UIImagePickerControllerDelegate & UINavigationControllerDelegate' before presenting UIImagePickerController.

Comment: @chillin', you cannot do that. The 'didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo' method will not be called if you do it this way.

Comment: The code you updated should work.

Comment: @Yun CHEN it still doesn't work, I actually had that code before I made the post, just forgot to include it. Any other ideas?

Comment: This works for me. Make a breakpoint on 'let picker' to check if it's be called?

Comment: @Yun CHEN breakpoint made, it is called. Would it make a difference if the `func handleSelectProfileImageView()` is called as a delegate from a different file?

Comment: Do you call it in a displayed ViewController?

Comment: I did: `weak var delegate: LoginControllerDelegate?

    func handleSelectProfileImageView() {
        delegate?.handleSelectProfileImageView()
    }`  and I called the function as the action for UITapGestureRecognizer